# Reference to a variable of different type

Tags: c++, reference

Is it possible to create a reference of an another data-type referring to a variable of a different datatype?

```
LPWSTR Buffer = new WCHAR[BUFFER_LEN];
LPBYTE& rfBuffer = (LPBYTE&) Buffer;
//Compiles but rfBuffer is BAD
```

Comment: When you use the C-style cast as you have above then a lot of things are "possible" but it doesn't mean that they are good things to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The syntax `T x = (T&)y` tells the compiler to treat the memory taken by the variable `y` as if a `T` was located there. But it's just a gross abuse of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Refrences are implicit pointors. They hold the address of the original object but behave syntactically as the object itself. According to this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7049scy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): *Any object whose address can be converted to a given pointer type can also be converted to the analogous reference type*